# Ubuntu-core from PXE?

Tags: boot, server, virtualbox, ubuntu-core, pxe

#### Problem in a few words...

I'm working with ubuntu-core22 and have to deploy a lot of computers with my custom OS. (ubuntu-core with my snaps).
I created my own PXE server. To make some test I install ubuntu-server-22.04.iso whitout any problemas.
But when I set to install ubuntu-core-22.img can't boot from PXE server.

My PXE serers runs in my laptop and the "VM" runs in a virtualBox.  This VM can comunicate with the pxe server and show te PXE Menu. This step help to me to affirm that PXE is running ok.
Then, the VM can boot ubuntu-server (ISO file ) but when boot from  .img file doesn't work.

I tried to "transform or convert"  .img in a .iso image, but doesn't works.

Seaching in the forum I saw this post, (with exact problem) but doesnt have any answers :(
[How do you netboot or network install ubuntu core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858610/how-do-you-netboot-or-network-install-ubuntu-core)

And then I searched in oficial documentation but nothing show PXE for ubuntu-core Examples
https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/search?q=pxe&siteSearch=https%3A%2F%2Fubuntu.com%2Fcore%2Fdocs
I'm working with ubuntu-core22 and have to deploy a lot of computers with my custom OS. (ubuntu-core with my snaps).
I created my own PXE server. To make some test I install ubuntu-server-22.04.iso whitout any problemas.
But when I set to install ubuntu-core-22.img can't boot from PXE server.

My PXE serers runs in my laptop and the "VM" runs in a virtualBox.  This VM can comunicate with the pxe server and show te PXE Menu. This step help to me to affirm that PXE is running ok.

Then, the VM can boot ubuntu-server (ISO file ) but when boot from  .img file doesn't work.

I tried to "transform or convert"  .img in a .iso image, but doesn't works.

Seaching in the forum I saw this post, (with exact problem) but doesnt have any answers :(
[How do you netboot or network install ubuntu core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858610/how-do-you-netboot-or-network-install-ubuntu-core)

I searched in oficial documentation but nothing show PXE for ubuntu-core Examples
https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/search?q=pxe&siteSearch=https%3A%2F%2Fubuntu.com%2Fcore%2Fdocs

And then I found this repo, that has a "solution" but not works. (I'm worried it's archived.)
https://github.com/korylprince/ubuntu-pxe

#### Details...

```
# My PXE Server works fine running on a docker-compose.
#
version: "3.5"
services: 
  pxe:
    network_mode: host
    container_name: dnsmasq_pxe_server
    image: dnsmasq_pxe_server:0.3
    build:
      context: dnsmasq_pxe
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - ./dnsmasq_pxe/dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf
      - ./dnsmasq_pxe/pxelinux.cfg:/tftp/bios/pxelinux.cfg/
      - ./dnsmasq_pxe/menu-pxelinux:/tftp/bios/menu
      - ./dnsmasq_pxe/menu-uefi/grub.cfg:/tftp/grub/grub.cfg
      - ./dnsmasq_pxe/tftp/bios:/tftp/bios
  apache:
    container_name: seabery.installer.apache_server
    image: 'bitnami/apache:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
    volumes:
      - /var/www/repository/welding-software:/app
      - ./apache/vhosts.conf:/vhosts/my_vhost.conf:ro
      - ./resources:/app/resources
      - ./installation_files/ISOs:/app/ISOs




# In my PXE config-menu I use this config
#
LABEL
        MENU LABEL [DEMO-TEST-01] - Ubuntu-server_22.04 [.iso file]
        KERNEL boot/DEMO/server/22.04/vmlinuz # Full path: dnsmasq_pxe/tftp/bios/...
        INITRD boot/DEMO/server/22.04/initrd  # Full path: dnsmasq_pxe/tftp/bios/...
        APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=2500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.0.41/ISOs/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.0.41/BM/cloud-init/base/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null ip=dhcp ---
        TEXT HELP
        Install Ubuntu Server 22.04 [amd64]
        ENDTEXT

LABEL
        MENU LABEL [DEMO-TEST-02] - Ubuntu-core22 [.img file]
        KERNEL boot/DEMO/server/22.04/vmlinuz # Full path: dnsmasq_pxe/tftp/bios/...
        INITRD boot/DEMO/server/22.04/initrd  # Full path: dnsmasq_pxe/tftp/bios/...
        APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=2500000 url=http://192.168.0.41/ISOs/ubuntu-core-22-amd64.iso autoinstall ip=dhcp
        TEXT HELP
        Install Ubuntu core 22 [amd64]
        ENDTEXT
```

Someone has the same problem?  "copy" or deploy ubuntu-core in a lot of machines ??

Beforehand thank you very much!
Jtan.

Comment: Ubuntu Core is designed to be directly written to device storage (not installed). It self-installs during boot. You should be able to create a Golden Master image in your VM and clone it to the target devices.